# Questions about memory management of a process

Tags: memory-management, process, operating-system, kernel, userspace

I have few question of operating system. I Google a lot but not able to find out any answer. Can anyone please help me.

Q1. How much memory is made available to a user program by the kernel, is there any limit to it?

Q2. What is the range of addresses a user program can have at max, what determines it?

Q3. What happens if excess memory is allocated to a user program, say malloc in an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1):

> Q1. How much memory is made available to a user program by the kernel, is there any limit to it?

Varies.In a modern system this is limited by process quotas, system parameters, and the page file size (and ultimately the virtual address space size of the hardware if you get there).

> Q2. What is the range of addresses a user program can have at max, what determines it?

Varies. This is determined by both the hardware and the operating system's configuration of the page tables. Some CPU types assign a fixed range of user addresses within the total virtual address space. Others have a single range of logical addresses and allow the OS to divide it up into user and system addresses. The latter is more flexible. The former allows paging of page tables.

> Q3. What happens if excess memory is allocated to a user program, say malloc in an infinite loop?

The allocation requests will fail. In the case of malloc, you'd get a null pointer returned. At the system service level, you'd get a failure code.

Comment: for Linux ans1) it is configurable ans2) it is also configurable (normally 0x00000000 - 0xbfffffff) ans 3)if one process allocating too much memory then other processes will be swapped to disk, ultimately thrashing of whole system and at a specific system will run out  of memory.